# How to add `n log n` stones to a grid to form a beautiful arrangement using divide-and-conquer? - algorithm idea

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence, divide-and-conquer

**Beautiful Courtyard Arrangement**

Our courtyard is a `10^9` by `10^9` grid. We have placed `n` stones at different integer coordinates to decorate our courtyard. However, the current arrangement is not beautiful. We have at most `n log n` additional stones to add to the arrangement in the courtyard. A beautiful arrangement is one where, for any two stones at coordinates `(x_1, y_1)` and `(x_2, y_2)`, one of the following conditions is met:

1. They are in the same row `(y_1 = y_2)`.
2. They are in the same column `(x_1 = x_2)`.
3. There is a stone at coordinates `(x_3, y_3)` such that:

   - `min(x_1, x_2) <= x_3 <= max(x_1, x_2)`
   - `min(y_1, y_2) <= y_3 <= max(y_1, y_2)`

Your task is to determine how many additional stones to add and where to place them to achieve a beautiful arrangement in the courtyard. Please note the following:

1. Stones must be placed at integer coordinates.
2. Two stones cannot occupy the same position.
3. The initial stones are fixed.
4. You cannot use more than n log n additional stones.

We are not looking for the minimum number of stones to achieve a beautiful arrangement, just a solution with less than or equal to `n log n` additional stones. The order of printing the coordinates does not matter.

**Input:**

- The first line contains an integer `n` `(2 <= n <= 2 * 10^4)`, the number of initial stones.
- The next `n` lines each contain two integers `x_i` and `y_i` `(1 <= x_i, y_i <= 10^9)`, the coordinates of the `i`-th stone.

**Output:**

- First, print an integer `m`, the number of additional stones needed to achieve a beautiful arrangement.
- Then, in the next `m` lines, print the coordinates `x_i` and `y_i` of the stones to be added to the courtyard.

**Sample Input 1:**

```
4
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

**Sample Output 1:**

```
0
```

**Sample Input 2:**

```
5
1 1
1 3
3 1
3 3
2 2
```

**Sample Output 2:**

```
4
1 2
2 1
3 2
2 3
```

I believe that a divide-and-conquer approach may be suitable for addressing this challenge. I've experimented with various scenarios using recurrence and divide-and-conquer techniques, yet I'm struggling to devise an efficient algorithm with a time complexity of `O(n log n)`. Given that it's possible to achieve `O(n log n)`, I presume the algorithm would follow the form `T(n) = kT(n/k) + Θ(n)`, indicating that we can break down the problem into `n/k` segments. However, I'm uncertain about how to implement this reduction and subsequently solve the issue. I would appreciate any suggestions, no matter how brief. Additionally, if there are pre-existing algorithms for this problem, sharing them would be immensely valuable.

Comment: what makes you think time complexity O(n log n) is possible? Don't you already need up to 3n(n-1)/2 == O(n^2) tests just to confirm the original arrangement isn't beautiful?

Comment: @jhnc Why would you want to confirm that?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI adding each single stone doesn't necessarily result in a beautiful arrangement, so some test is needed to decide whether to terminate adding more? yes, perhaps there is a faster way, but the question doesn't prove that, just asserts it

Comment: Divide the garden with a vertical line such that there are <n/2 stones to the left and to the right. Put a stone on the dividing line at every y coordinate that has another stone in either half (if that spot is empty). Repeat for each half.

Comment: @jhnc When you sort an array, do you test whether it is already sorted?

Comment: @jhnc The person who told me this problem (creator of this problem, I think) said it can be solved with `O(nlogn)`. Actually I have to solve it with `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yes, of course, but it's usually implicit in the algorithm unless one is doing a bogosort :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort the stones by `x` coordinate.  We will use this same sorting throughout the entire algorithm.

1. Find the column that contains the median element, by `x` coordinate, so that there are <= N/2 stones on each side
2. Recursively fix the stones on each side. Now all the pairings on each side are valid, so only pairings that use or cross the chosen column can be invalid.
3. For each `y` coordinate that contains a stone on either side, make sure the chosen column contains a stone with the same `y` coordinate.  Now there are no invalid pairings.

In step 3, since we only add stones to the chosen column, it only creates new pairings that use that column.  It also ensures that every pairing that uses or crosses the chosen column is valid:

```
   | |               | |
o  | |         => o  |o|
   | |     o         |o|     o
```

```
o     | |        o     |o|
      | |   =>         | |
      |o|              |o|
```

Furthermore, the recursive operations on each side do not increase the number of stones that the parent operation has to add, because they don't introduce stones at any *new* `y` coordinates.  As a result, there are at most N stones added at each of the ⌈log N⌉ levels, for a total of N⌈log N⌉.

To get this done in O(N log N) time, note that, after processing both sides in step 2, you do not need to process the *new* list of stones, which would be bigger than the original, because it doesn't introduce any new `y` coordinates.  Process the original smaller list instead.  Alternatively, process just the chosen columns on each side, because they use all `y` coordinates.  Either way, there are a total of N nodes processed at each recursive level.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get what do you mean by fixing each side in step 2. What is the base case for recursion and what do we do at that level? I have also another question. For example in the 2nd sample input in question body, the sorted array of stones would be {(1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (3,3)}. The median here is (2,2). So the line that splits the points is x=2. Then how do I continue recursively? {(1,1), (1,3)} and {(2,2), (3,1), (3,3)}?

Comment: The base case for the recursion is when there are 1 or zero stones, and therefore no pairs.  You don't need to include stones that are in the chosen column in there recursive calls, so if you have {(1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (3,3)} then the recursive calls are for  {(1,1), (1,3)} and {(3,1), (3,3)}.  In each of those calls you run the whole algorithm to add stones that ensure that all the pairings on that side are valid.

Comment: I cannot express my profound gratitude enough for your assistance in resolving the challenge. I have successfully surmounted the obstacle, and I am immensely appreciative of your invaluable support.